# Is XML a programming language?

Tags: xml

I often hear when people list the programming languages they know, they mention XML.

But is it even a programming language?

I consider XML as a "dataset" similar to JSON.

Moreover, I have seen companies requiring knowledge of XML but... what is much to know there?

Comment: Perhaps the following link will answer your question [XML - Wkipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)? Have a nice day :)

Comment: [Wikipedia says no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language).

Comment: @RayToal: Oh, thank god! I was worried that my many years of activity in the field of software development might prove useless! Phew! :)

Comment: Well, I understand that XML is a markup language and I have used it quite a lot. I just wanted to hear what more experienced people think about it. :) T

Comment: Ah but just because it is not a _programming language_ does not mean that it is not a _technology_ that people can put on their resume to announce to the world that (1) they know how to represent data in it, and (2) can use a library to manipulate that data.  As an aside, though, you can [represent programs in XML](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html), but that does not make XML a programming language.

Comment: Most people who write XML on their resume, actually know very little about XML and the surrounding technologies. If someone says they know XML, I would expect them to be familiar with push/pull parsing, as well as DOM manipulation. I'd expect familiarity with namespaces, DTD's, various schema languages and benefits and drawbacks of each.

The O'Reilly book [XML in a nutshell][1] has 714 pages, so this is by no means a simple technology.    

[1]: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007645.do

Comment: I think a lot of people get XML confused with XSLT, XPath, XQuery, etc. XML is not a turing complete programming language; it's just a "container language" or a "data description language" (sort of like HTML, JSON, YAML, etc.).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## A programming language?

First, **XML** is a format to represent data. It has originally be designed for this data to be essentially text documents or messages, but nothing prevents you from representing any data you wish, including programs. There at least three big examples of programs expressed in **XML** that come to mind:

1. **XSLT** is a [Turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) language whose only standard format is in XML, whose essential purpose is data transformations.
2. **ANT** is a task manager, used mostly for compilation management, whose tasks are described in XML.
3. **GCC-XML** is a format that GCC can use to output the result of its parsing of a source code.

On a more esoteric note, you could cite *o:XML*, a full-fledged **XML** programming language.

So as any **XML**, **DTD** or Schema semantically extends **XML** itself, you could technically argue that XML itself, through some of its extensions, **is** a programming language.

## Is there much to know?

Second, XML is a vast nebula of specifications, and most people only barely scratch the surface. Most people don't even imagine the corner cases in XML itself, let alone what's in XML Namespaces, XML Schema, XML Information Set, XQuery, XPath, XSLT, XSL-FO, XML Canonicalization, XML Signature, Efficient XML Interchange, XML Linking, etc.

So, yeah, I'd say there's plenty to know...

Answer (score 8):

XML is not a programming language.

There are programming languages that use XML syntax, notably XSL.

There is a lot to learn about XML, however.  The rules of its syntax, how namespaces and DTDs and schemas work, etc.  Also, programmers using XML need to how to interact with documents via the DOM and XPath even if the language they're using is not itself XML-based.

Answer (score 2):

XML isn't a programming language anymore than HTML is, however tons of people will also list HTML as a programming language, so it isn't surprising.

> what is much to know there?

XML has unique quirks about it, even though the libraries are quite powerful, knowing how to work with the libraries and knowing how to handle odd things the library cannot is very important.

For instance, the following would give you an "unexpected token at 0 : '&'" error, even though anyone with any XML experience would know what the problem really is. If you didn't know anything about XML it would look like garbage.

```
&lt;Root&gt;
    &lt;Leaf /&gt;
&lt;/Root&gt;
```

Comment: `If you didn't know anything about XML it would look like garbage.` That's the same for precisely everything in life, though, isn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I quoted the OP saying that XML was (paraphrasing) braindead easy. To give an example of a braindead syntax, INI files don't have any odd encoding, so can be much more easily picked up.

Comment: Okay but by extension if you took a valid INI file and corrupted it to the extent that you corrupted that XML, I bet that'd look like garbage to anyone too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't corrupt the XML, I failed to decode the XML encoded XML. That is simply some escaped syntax, it is actually a very minor change. There is no equivalent INI encoded INI.

Comment: Of course there is. You could "fail to decode" the bytes constituting an INI file into recognisable ASCII. You're merely biased into assuming that INI files will always be "legible" to someone familiar with them, which is no more or less true with XML :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You seem to be trying to disprove my point, yet you keep pointing to the difficulty inherit in encoding information, that doesn't disprove my point, it supports it. However your own answer says that XML is pointless and does not involve any skill. This is an odd thought given the complexity of namespaces alone.

Comment: You read the wrong answer; mine does not contain those words.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: INI files are plain text, so you can't really represent a value in multiple ways. If you want a property named foobar with a content of quux®, you have no choice but to insert a line with "foobar=quux®" as content (modulo some white space and quotes around value, depending on implementation). Anyone, without knowing the syntax, will fairly easily understand what that means. But a foobar element with quuux content could be encoded as <foobar>&#x71;&#x75&#75;&#x78&#xAE</foobar>. Unless you know ASCII hexadecimal codes by heart, you'll have no idea of the content...

Answer (score 0):

No.

It does not define ways to express computer programs.

It is a markup language, that defines ways to express data. When you say it's "similar" to JSON, you're correct — it's an equivalent thing.

People say a lot of things about XML and, usually, when you see a company requiring "knowledge of XML" it's only because they were part of the ridiculous XML "craze" in the management world in the mid-2000s and haven't even moved on from *that* yet. You can't really "know" all that much about XML, and it's unsuitable for a ton of things that management will insist XML is the job for, just because it's a buzzword.

Comment: I wouldn't say XML and JSON are equivalent. XML supports a lot of things JSON doesn't (namespaces are commonly cited, but there's more), simply because it's a whole markup language, and "extensible" at that, whereas JSON is just a way to combine a few atomic data types, arrays, and mappings. Of course, quite a few uses of XML don't use any of the features and might as well be using JSON, but that's another story.

Comment: XML is precisely as "extensible" as JSON.

Comment: Namespaces? Entities? Schemata? Comments? You can go ahead and define your own little way of doing those (provided you're skilled enough to add that functionality to a JSON parser), but with XML, these are actually standardized, used, and respected by tools. Or you could accept that JSON is a way to store data structured in certain ways, and XML is much more than that. Not to knock either, the intended use cases are quite different, and JSON beats XML in the areas it's specialized for.

Comment: XSLT is Turing-complete. Programs are data, after all.

Answer (score 0):

XML is not a programming language.

How much is there to know? Just browse the questions on StackOverflow that are tagged as XML questions.

Answer (score 0):

XML is not a programming language.

I agree with Wikipedia here: "A programming language is a notation for writing programs, which are specifications of a computation or algorithm."

There are programming languages whose syntax is in XML Yet, this doesn't make XML a programming language on its own. That's like saying plain text is a programming language because there are programming languages that can be expressed in plain text.

In other words, XML itself doesn't provide "specifications of a computation or algorithm".